# Javascript: getElementsById получить содержимое в переменную

Tags: javascript

```
$('.plus_summa').click(function () {
  var summa = document.getElementsById('summa').innerHTML;
  alert(summa.innerHTML);
  return false;
});
```

`TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function` — почему?

И как мне дальше с обычного текста перевести его в масив что бы уже работать с делением, умножением, и т.д.

Comment: # java!=javascript

Comment: `var summa = $('#summa').html();
alert(summa);
`

Comment: > java!=javascript

очень удивлен, что вижу подобное здесь всего лишь впервые

Comment: `java` и `javascript` разные языки программирования.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте

```
document.getElementById
```

Comment: тю елки, букву s не увидел. 5 утра сказываются. спасибо.